# How to view the number of NaNs in Spark data frame?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-ml

I'm using Spark data frames to process data and I'm interested in understanding how many NaNs I have in my dataset. I'm looking for something similar to pandas dataframes:

```
>>> dataset.isnull().sum()
PassengerId      0
Survived         0
Pclass           0
Name             0
Sex              0
Age            177
SibSp            0
Parch            0
Ticket           0
Fare             0
Cabin          687
Embarked         2
dtype: int64
```

This would be helpful in deciding whether to impute the missing values or simply drop them.

Comment: Are you using scala or python to code?

Comment: i'm using python